# HTML5 rendering

Tags: javascript, html

I always read something like HTML5 games etc. But I don't believe that a game is entirely programmed in HTML5 because it is just a markup language. Normally, it is controlled though JavaScript, right?

I want to program a very very simple browser game, that I can play with my friends. But I want to code the logic in Scala.

So I came up with this structure.
[image: logic]

The client is able to see HTML in his browser. HTML5 will be manipulated though JavaScript which opens a connection to my webserver (AJAX?). Now I can program all my logic in Scala and let JavaScript execute it (for example move pawn from position a to position b).

This would be possible, right?

As a webserver I would choose Lift.

But I have never done any rendering with JS/HTML5. Would you recommend to look in some frameworks such as [LimeJs](http://www.limejs.com/) or [CraftyJs](http://craftyjs.com/)?

Comment: Yes, the term "HTML5" is more often used for the [mightier APIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5#New_APIs) than for the new version of the markup language. BTW, the JS doesn't change the html markup, but the DOM which is built originally during the markup parsing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"HTML5" is commonly used as an all-encompassing reference to a set of specifications for client-side scripting language APIs, *in addition to* the core markup language that gave rise to the "ML" part in the name. So "implement this-or-that in HTML5" generally means something like do it in client-side Javascript, manipulating a DOM tree as specificied by HTML5 in order to present a user interface.

It is somewhat inconsistent/illogical naming, but standardizing on inconsistent illogical terminology is what this industry is best at. :-)

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5

> HTML5 is a markup language for structuring and presenting content for the World Wide Web, and is a core technology of the Internet originally proposed by Opera Software.[2] It is the fifth revision of the HTML standard ... a mixture of features introduced by various specifications, ... software products such as web browsers, ... common practice, and the many syntax errors in existing web documents. It is also an attempt to define a single markup language that can be written in either HTML or XHTML syntax
>
> **HTML5 on its own cannot be used for animation and interactivity - it must be supplemented with CSS3 or Javascript**

Sticking with your example developers typically define an API to access your data via your web server.

Javascript would be responsible for manipulating your view (html dom), so it would actually contain a big chunck of your game logic

webserver would contain your data model (maybe it would have logic for a robot player and its next move)

client is the browser